# how to assign value to array of array

Tags: arrays

I am trying to create an array of property_maps:  For example:: typedef property_map::type weightMaps;  weightMaps weights[10];  when I assign a value to the array would it be  graph_traits::edge_descriptor e;  In a loop of i to 10  weights[e][i]=x; or would it be weights[i][e]; or is it the wrong way to assign multiple properties to a graph?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.Hope it help someone:

weights[i][e]=x;

got it by trial and error.I think this applies anywhere.